# Firebase Realtime Database not being created in flutter while using firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

so I was making this sign up page in flutter using firebase authentication and realtime database. authentication works fine but I have a problem with database, it just isn't being created. I tried using push() as well, after following some instructions on google but it doesnt help. there aren't enough instructions on goggle regarding firebase realtime database. Any help will be appreciated!

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
```

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void registerNewUser(BuildContext context) async {
    final User firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailTextEditingController.text,
                password: passwordTextEditingController.text)
            .catchError((errMsg) {
      displayToastMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    }))
        .user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      Map userDataMap = {
        "name": nameTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "phone": phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),
      };
      usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);

      displayToastMessage("Account Created", context);
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);

      //here
    } else {
      displayToastMessage("Account Not Created", context);
    }
  }
```

debug Console

```
Launching lib/main.dart on M2003J15SC in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:46469/nnTIbYfPB8Q=/ws
I/GED     (24582): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
I/deu.lagdeuride(24582): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1227 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24582): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/System  (24582): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(24582): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System  (24582): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(24582): [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out(24582): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System  (24582): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(24582): [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out(24582): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
W/System  (24582): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out(24582): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System  (24582): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(24582): [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out(24582): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/FirebaseAuth(24582): Notifying id token listeners about user ( hULpKuZcGNhVE45xcR5RkrlCPTl1 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(24582): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( hULpKuZcGNhVE45xcR5RkrlCPTl1 ).
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast](24582): hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/Toast   (24582): Show toast from OpPackageName:com.lagdeu.lagdeurider, PackageName:com.lagdeu.lagdeurider
D/Surface (24582): Surface::connect(this=0x77eefc2000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys(24582): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/Surface (24582): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x77eefc2000,bufferCount=3)
D/Surface (24582): Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x77eefc2000)
I/System.out(24582): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System  (24582): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(24582): [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
D/Surface (24582): Surface::disconnect(this=0x77eefc2000,api=1)
D/View    (24582): [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{7763522 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-564,316}
```

output is empty.

Comment: It's hard to correlate the debug output you shared to the code you also shared. When you step through your code line-by-line in the debugger, what output is generated when/right after the `usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);`?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
   final User? firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailtextEditingController.text,
        password: passwordtextEditingController.text)
    .catchError((errMsg) {
  displayToastMessage(errMsg.toString(), context);
})).user;
```

Add a  "?" after User ..

Comment: Please do not add religious, theistic, evangelist, superstitious or other irrelevant material here - technical writing is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried the same thing with this code and got this on console:

W/PersistentConnection(17703): pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://flutter-uber-clone-220d2-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app

Solution:

1. Either you change your database URL to said link, or
2. Recreate your project with closer regional time

You also can check this:
[Firebase Realtime Database connection killed: Different Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806876/firebase-realtime-database-connection-killed-different-region)