# addValueEventListener event is not firing up in Android Studio using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need read data from my Firebase database.I will try my best but the addValueListener not fire.

```
DatabaseReference referenceParty = database.getReference();
referenceParty.child("Party").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            PartyInf info = snapshot.getValue(PartyInf.class);
            String acCode = info.getAC_Code();
            String acName = info.getAC_Name();
            String arCode = info.getArea_Code();
            PartyExist = dbMain.hasObjectParty(Integer.parseInt(acCode));
            if (PartyExist == false && !acName.trim().equals("")) {
               dbMain.addParty(Integer.parseInt(acCode), acName, Integer.parseInt(arCode));
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

Comment: The first step is to implement `onCancelled` so that you don't ignore errors. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. --- Then check if either `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` is called by running in a debugger. If neither is called, you might not have configured your database URL correctly, and you can pass it into the API call with: `DatabaseReference referenceParty = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here").getReference();` For mre on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68806876

Comment: Make sure your Firebase database path is correct and you are writing data to the correct path.

Comment: I will try this but still no result.Neither onDataChenge or  onCancelled not called

 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://easypay-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com");
        DatabaseReference referenceArea = database.getReference("Area");

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez that i checked . It's correct

Comment: On your question, you are writing to Party?

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez Area & Party exist.Both not working

Comment: Can you make sure your google-services.json is correct? And review your database rules on Firebase admin.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez "google-services.json" i already checked it's correct. my database rule is   {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez  It's not code side error.It's emulator's based bug.I turn off emulator wifi.Then it's work correctly.

Comment: @tsrahul81 thanks for the update! Yes always test on a device. I don't trust Android emulators.

Answer (score 1):

It was not a problem with my code. It turned out to be an emulator bug. I turned off the emulator's wifi, then it works correctly.